# PHP form in AJAX no return

Tags: php, ajax

Is it possible to get a return value in AJAX(javascript) from a PHP form?

This is my PHP form in AJAX:

```
function start()
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (xhr == null)
    {
        alert('Probleem met het maken van het XMLHttpRequest object');
        return;
    }

    var url="xml/Producten.xml";


    if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked)
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=alles;
    }
    else
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=drank;
    }



    xhr.open("Get",url,true);
    xhr.send(null); 
}
function alles()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
        var strOutput;

        strOutput="<table class='product'><tr>";

        var aantal = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam").length;

        for (var i=0; i<aantal; i++)
        {
            strOutput += "<td><p><img src='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'></p>";
            strOutput += "<p>&euro; " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("prijs")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
            strOutput += "<p>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
            strOutput += "<p><form action='' method='POST'>";
            strOutput += "<input class= 'nummers' type='number' name='aantal' min='1' max='20'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='submit' value='In mandje' name= 'toevoegen'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + i +"'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"'>";
            strOutput += "</form></p></td>";    

        }
        strOutput += "</table>";
    }
    document.getElementById("tekstBox").innerHTML = strOutput;
}
```

When I run this script, it gives no errors but I'm getting no return value either. I'm asking this because I'm pretty new to AJAX.

This is where I call my function `start()`:

```
<form action="">
<p><input class="radio" id="radio1" type="radio" onclick="start()" name="type" value="Alles" checked="checked">Alles</p>
<p><input class="radio" id="radio2" type="radio" onclick="start()" name="type" value="Pizza">Pizza</p>
<p><input class="radio" id="radio3" type="radio" onclick="start()" name="type" value="Voorgerecht">Voorgerecht</p>
<p><input class="radio" id="radio4" type="radio" onclick="start()" name="type" value="Dessert">Dessert</p>
<p><input class="radio" id="radio5" type="radio" onclick="start()" name="type" value="Drank">Drank</p>
</form>
```

**Answer:**

The `i` in the `for` loop must have started from 1, and not from 0 because the id of my products began from 1.

Comment: use jQuery insted of javascript for batter perfomance

Comment: Have you seen in console???may be there is error is shown??

Comment: Have you called the `start()` function? Where?

Comment: @IshanShah — How does loading a chunky library that wraps everything you want to do with additional function calls give you better performance?

Comment: `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` – Globals are a pain to work with at the best of times. Globals + Asynchronous requests will give you race conditions. **Don't use globals** for this.

Comment: "I'm getting no return value either" — You have no return statement anywhere in your code, so that isn't really surprising. I suspect you don't mean *return value* though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question, yes it is very much possible to get a return value with Ajax from a php script, it's why Ajax is used pretty much.

While I'm not entire sure why your current script is not working, it does not surprise me as it's just not the way you want to do this.

Look into jQuery, it's the best way to apply Javascript to your projects, especially if you're trying to use Ajax  to chance your webpages content.

```
$.get("xml/Producten.xml", function (result) {
    //this is the success result handler,
    //result contains whatever you return in your php script.
    var radio = $("#radio1"); //getElementById.

    //etc
});
```

I can assist you some more with jQuery should you choose to take this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The callback functions `alles` & `drank` reference the variable `xml` which looks to have been declared ( or rather simply instantiated ) within the ajax function. Either declare the xml var globally (ie: `var xml;` ) or pass as a reference to it or the response to the callback. The code below passes the response to the callback rather than the xhr object itself.

```
function start(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr == null){
        alert('Probleem met het maken van het XMLHttpRequest object');
        return;
    }
    var url="xml/Producten.xml";

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {
            var callback=document.getElementById("radio1").checked ? alles : drank;
            callback.call( this, xhr.responseXML );
        }
    };
    xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
    xhr.send( null ); 
}

function alles(r){
    if (r) {
        var xmlDoc = r;
        var strOutput;

        strOutput="<table class='product'>";

        var aantal = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam").length;

        for (var i=0; i<aantal; i++) {
            strOutput += "<tr><td><p><img src='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'></p>";
            strOutput += "<p>&euro; " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("prijs")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
            strOutput += "<p>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
            strOutput += "<p><form action='' method='POST'>";
            strOutput += "<input class= 'nummers' type='number' name='aantal' min='1' max='20'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='submit' value='In mandje' name= 'toevoegen'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + i +"'>";
            strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"'>";
            strOutput += "</form></p></td></tr>";    
        }
        strOutput += "</table>";
    }
    document.getElementById("tekstBox").innerHTML = strOutput;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting no terurn value when I run your script

Comment: How and where do you use the `start` function? The code does work - tested it and seems fine.

Comment: Using your html code it works ~ see screenshot: http://imgur.com/gallery/j3jkvHB Are you seeing the request in the console?

Comment: Yeah i'm getting al the information from my XML file, but the code in my php above won't run: http://pastebin.com/AF8BtNyp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98896/discussion-between-ramraider-and-manariba).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are executing the function `alles` here:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=alles;
```

and assigning the RESULT of that function (which in this case is `undefined`) to `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Now, when the readystate changes, `XMLHttpRequest` attempts to call `onreadystatechange` which is now `undefined`, so nothing will happen.

So your `alles()` function should be like this:

```
function alles(){

    return function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
                var strOutput;

                strOutput="<table class='product'><tr>";

                var aantal = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam").length;

                for (var i=0; i<aantal; i++){
                    strOutput += "<td><p><img src='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'></p>";
                    strOutput += "<p>&euro; " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("prijs")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
                    strOutput += "<p>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("naam")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
                    strOutput += "<p><form action='' method='POST'>";
                    strOutput += "<input class= 'nummers' type='number' name='aantal' min='1' max='20'>";
                    strOutput += "<input type='submit' value='In mandje' name= 'toevoegen'>";
                    strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + i +"'>";
                    strOutput += "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"'>";
                    strOutput += "</form></p></td>";    

                }
                strOutput += "</table>";
                document.getElementById("tekstBox").innerHTML = strOutput;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you are still assigning the result of the function to `xhr.onreadystatechange`, but this time it is a callable function instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @Manariba Install [firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in your browser. It will help you debug the issue.

Comment: @Manariba I've include this line, `document.getElementById("tekstBox").innerHTML = strOutput;` inside `if` block. Please test your application with the updated code.

Comment: I still got an empty page...I don't understand?